# Store MonthName() function in a string variable

Tags: vba, ms-access-2013

First question here so go easy on me!

I am new to Visual Basic (but not programming) and I am having trouble on a project I am working on for a local organization.

I have a button that runs a query that contains a single `"SELECT ... INTO ... "` statement.  This statement also looks for every record where the field `RecievedBoxToday` is equal to `"Yes"`.  Here is the code that is working just fine:

```
SELECT * INTO RENAME_THIS_TABLE
FROM [DATABASE ZERO]
WHERE (([DATABASE ZERO].RecievedBoxToday)=Yes);
```

Now here is the problem (besides the fact that `Received` is spelled wrong):  This code will be ran every month, but the table (`RENAME_THIS_TABLE`) is over-written every time the button is clicked.  I would like to have permanent data for every month so my solution is to rename the `RENAME_THIS_TABLE` table to `MONTHNAME_YEAR` where `MONTHNAME` is the name of the month (January or December) and `YEAR` is the current year (2015).  I thought I could go about doing this with the `MonthName()` function, which works just fine, but I want to be able to store this month name into a string to be concatenated with the year (also a string).  Afterwords this string will replace `RENAME_THIS_TABLE`.

My code for this that doesn't seem to work is:

```
dim Month As String
dim Year As String

MonthName(Month(Date()), False) As Month
Year(Date()) As Year

dim NewName As String = Month + "_" + Year
```

After this I'm not sure where to go as far as taking this new string variable and inserting into the SQL code, where it will replace `RENAME_THIS TABLE`.

How can I make this work?  Can I make this work?  If it matters, I am using VBA with Microsoft Access 2013.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Declarations (`Dim`, `Public` or `Private`) are optional in VBA, but if you give them, they should be in a separate statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `Month` and `Year` as variable names. Those are reserved (function) names in VBA. Also, as a shortcut, you can just use the `Format()` function to format your date string:

```
Dim strNewName As String
strNewName = Format(Date, "mmmm_yyyy")    ' => "August_2015"
```

If your SQL statement is stored in a separate string, you can just concatenate your new table name into your string:

```
Dim strSql As String
strSql = "SELECT * INTO " & strNewName & " FROM [DATABASE ZERO] WHERE (([DATABASE ZERO].RecievedBoxToday)=Yes);"
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!  Thanks Bond!